# Burninate the [study] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-cleanup-proposal

The tag wiki excerprt for [study](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/study) reads:

> Selecting a field of study, preparing for exams or assignments, or pertaining to designing research studies

With other words, the creator of this excerpt wanted the tag to be applied to three different topics, which is the total opposite of what tags should be like and renders the tag very useless.

I thus request to burninate this tag. There are only 16 questions in this tag, which could all do with more specific tags.

Comment: +1 for burnination. But what are the replacements?

Comment: @aeismail: The very problem of this tag is that it is too broad, so there is no ubiquitous replacement. Also, there are only three questions which have no other tag than *study.* If it helps, I can retag these questions myself (or perform the entire burnination manually). I do not know about the requirements of a burnination.

Comment: How can we burninate without a Trogdor?

Comment: @StrongBad I believe that you should be in a good position to sketch the necessary dragon-man...

Comment: @aeismail `research-studies` is the only one from that list I'd feel appropriate. Preparing for exams or assignments might be more appropriate for workplace.SE, and you will be hard-pressed to find people who are experts on a tag known as `field-of-study` versus something as concrete as `computer-science`.

Comment: @Compass: Research studies are already covered by [tag:research], albeit this tag being heavily overused. That is unless you are talking about studies which investigate research itself, in which case I wouldn’t know a tag for it but also neither of the questions tagged *study* is about this, IIRC.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft maybe a sub-tag called `study-design` then.

Comment: @Compass: What for? Skimming through the questions tagged *study,* I found only [one question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4784/7734) touching the topic of study design and this is not in dire need of a new tag. Also, all but the most general questions on study design (such as the linked one) would be off-topic here, as they relate to the individual field.

Comment: What's the difference between [tag:study] and [tag:education] tags? Cannot [tag:study] be synonym of [tag:education]?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: Not all the questions currently under [tag:study] fit under [tag:education]. (Also, [tag:education] is horribly broad in my opinion.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd support burning this tag to the ground. Suggested replacements:

- Some unholy hybrid of `changing-fields`, `career-path` etc. Just "selecting a field of study" is almost broad enough to be useless.
- `exams` (which we already have) or if we *really* felt like we needed a new one, `exam-prep`?
- `study-design`, which in my mind should also pretty much auto-flag a question as potentially needing to be shuffled to a subject-specific SE or CrossValidated.